# How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to get an output of an `Exec`'ed executable?

I want to show the user an info query page, but show the default value of MAC address in the input box. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, use redirection of the standard output to a file:

```pascal
[Code]

function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
var
  TmpFileName, ExecStdout: string;
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  if CurPage = wpWelcome then begin
    TmpFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\ipconfig_results.txt';
    Exec('cmd.exe', '/C ipconfig /ALL > "' + TmpFileName + '"', '', SW_HIDE,
      ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    if LoadStringFromFile(TmpFileName, ExecStdout) then begin
      MsgBox(ExecStdout, mbInformation, MB_OK);
      { do something with contents of file... }
    end;
    DeleteFile(TmpFileName);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Note that there may be more than one network adapter, and consequently several MAC addresses to choose from.

Comment: Note that rather than hard-coding "cmd.exe" it's better practice to use `ExpandConstant('{cmd}')`.  (Of course, it's better still to use proper APIs instead of trying to capture the output of console commands, as the latter may change without notice, since it's intended for humans.)

Comment: For clarification: you need to run your program through the command prompt to get redirection. I initially looked at this answer and was confused why this wasn't working for me, the reason was because I didn't realise redirection is a function of the command prompt rather than windows, so you need to Exec on cmd.exe /c <command> <parameters>

Comment: for unicode installation, must use: `var ExecStdout: AnsiString;`

Comment: You can't directly use this technique with powershell because it generates utf16 filename with BOM. InnoSetup does not seem to provide any conversion function.

Comment: if the file already exists, will this overwrite it?

Comment: @Smith Yes. `>>` to append. https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-redirect-command-output-to-a-file-2618084

Answer (score 27):

I had to do the same (execute command line calls and get the result) and came up with a more general solution.

It also fixes strange bugs if quoted paths are used in the actual calls by using the `/S` flag for `cmd.exe`.

```pascal
// Exec with output stored in result.
// ResultString will only be altered if True is returned.
function ExecWithResult(
  Filename, Params, WorkingDir: String; ShowCmd: Integer;
  Wait: TExecWait; var ResultCode: Integer; var ResultString: String): Boolean;
var
  TempFilename: String;
  Command: String;
  ResultStringAnsi: AnsiString;
begin
  TempFilename := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\~execwithresult.txt');
  // Exec via cmd and redirect output to file.
  // Must use special string-behavior to work.
  Command :=
    Format('"%s" /S /C ""%s" %s > "%s""', [
      ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), Filename, Params, TempFilename]);
  Result :=
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), Command, WorkingDir, ShowCmd, Wait, ResultCode);
  if not Result then
    Exit;
  LoadStringFromFile(TempFilename, ResultStringAnsi); // Cannot fail
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20912510/850848
  ResultString := ResultStringAnsi;
  DeleteFile(TempFilename);
  // Remove new-line at the end
  if (Length(ResultString) >= 2) and
     (ResultString[Length(ResultString) - 1] = #13) and
     (ResultString[Length(ResultString)] = #10) then
    Delete(ResultString, Length(ResultString) - 1, 2);
end;
```

Usage:

```pascal
Success :=
  ExecWithResult('ipconfig', '/all', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated,
    ResultCode, ExecStdout) and
  (ResultCode = 0);
```

The result can also be loaded into a `TStringList` object to get all lines:

```pascal
Lines := TStringList.Create;
Lines.Text := ExecStdout;
// ... some code ...
Lines.Free;
```

Comment: One minor issue in your Usage example:  if the Exec succeeds but ResultCode <> 0, ResultCode will be filled in with the exit code of the called program, not with a windows error, so SysErrorMessage will not get the correct message. Also, a non-zero exit code can sometimes be okay. I'd recommend testing ResultCode separately depending on the context. More info on this confusion:  https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/190.

Comment: Yes the exception message in the example relies on windows exit-codes => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx

Comment: That is the reference for MS *error* codes returned by [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx). *Exit* codes come from [GetExitCodeProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and are not necessarily the same thing. For example, `ipconfig /?` is not an error but returns exit code 1. And if you use ewNoWait or ewWaitUntilIdle, the ResultCode will always be 259, which is a reserved code from the GetExitCodeProcess function meaning STILL_ACTIVE.

Comment: Ok I removed the Exception part in the example. This depends on what is actually done anyway. Just wanted to show that the result is passed to InnoSetup and can be used.

Comment: What is the `or (ResultCode <> 0)`? Shouldn't it be `and (ResultCode = 0)`?

Comment: I had a problem with a JAVA_HOME path that contained spaces and I was not able to make it work using the solution proposed in the accepted answer. However, thank to this solution that avoids the bugs when quotes are in the path, I was successfully able to get the version of Java referenced by JAVA_HOME. The only thing I had to add was the redirection of the Standard Error `2>&1` as `java -version` makes use of it.