# Inno Setup - get an output of an Exec

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have referenced [How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136770/how-to-get-an-output-of-an-execed-program-in-inno-setup). But my txt file always empty.
Here is my script:

```
[Code] 
function MyTest(): Boolean;
Var
  TmpFileName: String;
  ExecStdout: AnsiString;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  TmpFileName := 'C:\Users\My\Desktop\123.txt';
  Exec('C:\Users\My\Desktop\devcon.exe', 'help find > "' + TmpFileName + '"', '', SW_SHOW, 
    ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  if LoadStringFromFile(TmpFileName, ExecStdout) then
  begin
    MsgBox(ExecStdout, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;           
  //DeleteFile(TmpFileName);
  Result := true;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): boolean;
begin
  MyTest;
  Result := true;
end;
```

Comment: This is not the code from the question your reference. Where is the `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of [How does output redirection work in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11441938/850848)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes..but I'm not very clear about  that answer.

Comment: What is  `{cmd} /c actual-command-line > output-file` mean?

Comment: It means: run `actual-command-line` and redirect its output to `output-file`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I solved this problem. Here is my code: `Exec('cmd.exe', '/C ' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\devcon.exe') + ' help find > ' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}\123.txt'), '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);`  Thanks a lot.