# LoadStringFromFile and StringChangeEx from Unicode Inno Setup (Ansi file)

Tags: unicode, inno-setup, ansi, pascalscript

I'm trying to update one of my scripts to use the Unicode version of Inno Setup. Unfortunately I'm running into a problem where `StringChangeEx` is expecting to see a unicode `String` instead of the `AnsiString` that I need (mismatched type). Is there an alternate way to replace matching `AnsiString` from Unicode Inno Setup?

I'm using `WizardDirValue()` to avoid having to type `ExpandConstant('{app}\')` all the time, in case anyone wonders why.

```pascal
var
  AnsiData: AnsiString;
begin
  LoadStringFromFile(WizardDirValue() + '\legacyansi.conf', AnsiData)
  // Type mismatch, StringChangeEx expects String which is Unicode
  StringChangeEx(AnsiData, 'current', 'replace', True);
  SaveStringToFile(WizardDirValue() + '\legacyansi.conf', AnsiData)
end;
```

Comment: The answer my @TLama is a quick solution. But if you actually need to read "Unicode" file, see [Inno Setup Reading file in Ansi and Unicode encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38968230/850848).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since parameters of [`LoadStringFromFile`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_loadstringfromfile.htm) as well as of [`StringChangeEx`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_stringchangeex.htm) functions are declared, they expect the exact type to be passed, so there's not much to do with it. You will need just to declare another variable just for your [`StringChangeEx`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_stringchangeex.htm) function call and typecast between ANSI & Unicode string types:

```pascal
var
  UnicodeStr: string;
  ANSIStr: AnsiString;
begin
  if LoadStringFromFile('C:\File.txt', ANSIStr) then
  begin
    UnicodeStr := String(ANSIStr);
    if StringChangeEx(UnicodeStr, 'FromStr', 'ToStr', True) > 0 then
      SaveStringToFile('C:\File.txt', AnsiString(UnicodeStr), False);
  end;
end;
```

Annoying, isn't it ?