# Reading file in Ansi and Unicode encoding in Inno Setup

Tags: unicode, inno-setup, ansi

I have a function called `GetServerName`. I need to pass the file name (say for example 'test.txt') as well as a needed section string (say for example 'server')

The `test.txt` file is contains something like this

```
data1 | abcd
data2 | efgh
server| 'serverName1'
data3 | ijkl
```

I need to extract server name so in my function I will pass something like `GetServerName('test.txt', 'server')` and it should return `serverName1`.

My problem is that the `test.txt` was an ANSI-encoded file earlier. Now it can be an ANSI-encoded file or Unicode-encoded file. Below function worked correctly for ANSI-encoded file, but giving problem, if file is encoded in UNICODE. I suspect something with `LoadStringsFromFile` function. Because when, I debug I could see it returns Unicode characters instead of human readable characters. How to solve my issue simply? (or how to find the type of encoding of my file and how to convert UNICODE string to ANSI for comparison, then I can do it myself)

```pascal
function GetServerName(const FileName, Section: string): string;
//Get Smartlink server name
var
  DirLine: Integer;
  LineCount: Integer;
  SectionLine: Integer;   
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  //Lines: String;
  AHA: TArrayOfString;
begin
  Result := '';
  if LoadStringsFromFile(FileName, Lines) then
  begin
    LineCount := GetArrayLength(Lines);
    for SectionLine := 0 to LineCount - 1 do
    begin
      AHA := StrSplit(Trim(Lines[SectionLine]), '|')
      if AHA[0] = Section then
      begin
       Result := AHA[1];
       Exit;
      end
    end
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*First, note that the Unicode is not an encoding. The Unicode is a character set. Encoding is [UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings) etc. So we do not know which encoding you actually use.*

---

In the Unicode version of Inno Setup, the [`LoadStringsFromFile` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringsfromfile) (plural – do not confuse with singular [`LoadStringFromFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringfromfile)) uses the current Windows Ansi encoding by default.

But, if the file has the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), it will treat the contents accordingly. The BOM is a common way to autodetect the UTF-8 (and other UTF-*) encoding. You can create a file in the UTF-8 encoding with BOM using Windows Notepad.

UTF-16 or other encodings are not supported natively.

For implementation of reading UTF-16 file, see [Reading UTF-16 file in Inno Setup Pascal script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39844156/850848#39845057).

For working with files in any encoding, including UTF-8 without BOM, see [Inno Setup - Convert array of string to Unicode and back to ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46257538/850848) or [Inno Setup replace a string in a UTF-8 file without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54333050/850848).