# inno setup to check any network intercepting traffic like zscaler

Tags: inno-setup, traceroute

As a pre-install i need to check if zscaler or any similar program is intercepting the traffic. Can I use `tracert` for this? if so , can i just run as shellexec? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Using tracert is possible - you need to catch the output of the cmd (see this example: [How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136770/how-to-get-the-output-of-an-execed-program-in-inno-setup))

But the tricky part is how to process that ouput? (The output is simple text.)

Do you want to parse it manually directly in Inno script? Or you have  some utility to do this?

This may be a really tough task as there are many possibilities and options.

Comment: If the OP is going to detect traffic redirectors (or interceptors), then using tracert is pointless for the overall task since such device (or application) may return whatever they wants to the ICMP requests. Except that, using a pure ICMP API (basically 3 functions & 3 structures, not counting IP address conversion functions) might be much more easier than parsing language dependent output files (for IPv4 only).

Comment: @Slappy sorry for late response, thanks for the answer, As of now I dont have any utility to parse the output, may have to do within Inno itself.

Comment: @TLama Can you please elaborate on what you mean? using pure ICMP API, what is that and how can I use it here?