# Using the "uses" statement in Inno Setup Code section

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to use the `uses` statement to implement something like in the following example:

```pascal
uses Process;
...
var s : ansistring;
...
if RunCommand('/bin/bash',['-c','echo $PATH'],s) then
   writeln(s);
```

The `uses` statement causes an error during compilation. 
Any idea why?

Comment: `/bin/bash`? Inno Setup is Windows application, not *nix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `uses` statement in the Inno Setup/Pascal Script.

---

You can use only the [functions listed in Inno Setup documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions).

To add new functions, you have two options:

- [import them from a DLL](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll) like:

  ```pascal
  procedure MyDllFunc(hWnd: Integer; lpText, lpCaption: AnsiString; uType: Cardinal);
  external 'MyDllFunc@files:MyDll.dll stdcall';
  ```
- include them from another file using the [`#include` preprocessor directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=include).

  ```
  #include "MyFunctions.pas"
  ```

---

Anyway, to answer your real question, use the [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec).

To collect an output of the executed command, see [How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1136770/850848)

Comment: Thanks @Martin Prikryl. That first part answers my question.    

What i am actually trying to achieve is to run the tzutil application and use the returned value (string or integer)