# inno setup checks whether the .net6 runtime is installed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, inno-setup

I'm using inno setup for the first time, and I've been tormented with this problem for a day, and desperately need help.
I use VS to compile a WPF program, which depends on the .net6 runtime. I want to detect whether the user has the .net6 runtime during installation. If not, install the corresponding .net6 runtime. I want to know how to achieve it through inno setup
I have downloaded the x86 and x64 versions of the .net6 runtime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479992/check-if-net-5-0-is-installed-in-inno-setup

Answer (score 0):

This script uses the downloader and should do the job:

```
[Setup]
AppName=SO Demo Code
AppVersion=<Your Verision>
DefaultDirName={pf}\SO Demo Code

[Files]
Source: "<Your Path>\dotnet-runtime-downloader.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Code]
function IsDotNet6Installed: Boolean;
var
  regVersion: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v6.0', 'Version', regVersion);
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  dotNet6Installed: Boolean;
  dotNetDownloaderPath: string;
  dotNetDownloaderArgs: string;
  downloadResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  
  dotNet6Installed := IsDotNet6Installed;

  if not dotNet6Installed then
  begin
    MsgBox('The .NET 6 runtime is required. Downloading and installing it now.', mbInformation, MB_OK);

    dotNetDownloaderPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotnet-runtime-downloader.exe');
    dotNetDownloaderArgs := 'https://path/to/dotnet-runtime-x86-6.0.0-win.exe,https://path/to/dotnet-runtime-x64-6.0.0-win.exe';

    ExtractTemporaryFile('dotnet-runtime-downloader.exe');

    // Run the downloader to fetch the .NET 6 runtime installers
    Exec(dotNetDownloaderPath, dotNetDownloaderArgs, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, downloadResultCode);

    dotNet6Installed := IsDotNet6Installed;

    if not dotNet6Installed then
    begin
      MsgBox('Failed to download and install the .NET 6 runtime. Setup will now exit.', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```