Detecting .NET 8 desktop runtime is installed in Inno Setup
I use the following code in Inno Setup to install .NET 8 Desktop runtime:
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var             
  dotNetDownloaderPath: string;
  dotNetDownloaderArgs: string;
  downloadResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;    

  dotNetDownloaderPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\windowsdesktop-runtime-8.0.3-win-x64.exe');
  dotNetDownloaderArgs := '';

  ExtractTemporaryFile('windowsdesktop-runtime-8.0.3-win-x64.exe');

  // Run the downloader to fetch the .NET 8 runtime installers
  Exec(dotNetDownloaderPath, dotNetDownloaderArgs, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, downloadResultCode);    
 

end;

It works but I need to skip installation in case .NET 8 Desktop runtime is already installed on the machine.
Is it a registry key with which I can detect .NET 8 Desktop runtime is installed?
Or please suggest some other way.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72479992/850848

I implemented what I needed with the help of InnoDependencyInstaller
and adding to the installer the following code:
[Code]
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin    
  Dependency_AddDotNet80;     
  Dependency_AddDotNet80Desktop;   

  Result := True;
end;

It seems to work correctly for .NET 8.

There is an issue when running netcorecheck.exe or netcorecheck_x64.exe during installation if certain security software is present. Specifically, I encountered this problem with WithSecure, which interrupts the installation process with the following error message:
The file in the temporary directory could not be executed. The installation was interrupted.
Error 5: Access denied.

@PiotrStęclik I haven't encountered this, probably you could post a new Issue to their github
